# Can we have terminal states in NuSMV?

Tags: verification, nusmv

Is it possible to have a state in NuSMV that does not have transitions to any other states? For example is it valid that in my code l3 does not have any transitions? When I run this NuSMV gives me the error that "case conditions are not exhaustive". Thanks!

```
MODULE main

VAR

location: {l1,l2,l3};


ASSIGN

init(location):=l1;

next(location):= case
             (location = l1): l2;
             (location = l2): l1;
             (location = l2): l3;
             esac;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By construction, in the so-called *assignment-style* [used in your model]:

- there is always at least one initial state
- all states have at least one next state
- non-determinism is apparent

Alternatively, one can use the so-called *constraint-style*, which allows for:

- inconsistent `INIT` constraints, which result in no initial state
- inconsistent `TRANS` constraints, which result in  deadlock states *(i.e. a state without any outgoing transition to some next state)*
- non-determinism is hidden

For more info, see [the second part of this course](http://www.patricktrentin.com/pages/fm2018.html), which applies also to `NuSMV` for the most part.

---

An example of a FSM wherein some state has no future state is:

```
MODULE main
VAR b : boolean;
TRANS b -> FALSE;
```

The state in which `b` is `true` has no future state.
Conversely, the state in which `b` is `false` can loop in itself or go to the state in which `b = true`.

You can use the command `check_fsm` to detect deadlock states.

---

Please note that the presence of deadlock states can hinder the correctness of model checking in some situations. For instance:

> [FAQ #007:](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/faq.html#007) CTL specification with top level existential path quantifier
>   is wrongly reported as being violated. For example, for the model
>   below both specifications are reported to be false though one is just
>   the negation of the other! I know such problems can arise with
>   deadlock states, but running it with -ctt says that everything is
>   fine.
>
> ```
> MODULE main
> VAR b : boolean;
> TRANS next(b) = b;
> CTLSPEC EF b
> CTLSPEC !(EF b)
> ```

For other **critical** consequences of *deadlock* states in the transition relation, see [this page](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/faq.html).

---

Usually, when `NuSMV` says that *"the case conditions are not exhaustive"* one adds a *default action* with a `TRUE` condition at the end of the `case` construct, which is triggered when none of the previous conditions applies. The most common choice for the *default action* is a *self-loop*, which is encoded as follows:

```
MODULE main
VAR
  location: {l1,l2,l3};
ASSIGN
  init(location):= l1;
  next(location):=
    case
      (location = l1): l2;
      (location = l2): {l1, l3};
      TRUE           : location;
    esac;
```

**NOTE:** please notice that if there are multiple conditions with the same *guard*, only the first of these conditions is ever used. For this reason, when in your model `location = l2` then the next value of `location` can only be `l1` and never `l3`. To fix this, and have some non-deterministic choice among `l1` and `l3`, one must list all possible future values under the same condition as a **set** of values (i.e. `{l1, l3}`).